# Inside and outside of for-loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, so could someone explain this (in my opinion) strange behaviour (code below)?

The second console.log prints 5 to the console, despite the fact that loop defines that `a` should be less than 5. Additionally, the second console.log is outside the loop. I understand that assigning value to the "let" instead of "var" generates different results, but I am curious why JavaScript behaves that way. Does JavaScript somehow "export" that 5 outside the loop?

I am a little bit confused.

```js
for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
  console.log("Number inside is " + a);
};

// Prints: "Number inside is 0...1...2...3...4"

console.log("Number outside is " + a);
// Prints: "Number outside is 5
```

Comment: You should pre-increment using `++a`. With `a++` you are making JS cache and optimise the value, which may be dangerous in certain scenarios and is most certainly less efficient. The output will be the same in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a++` increments variable `a` by 1 after its execution.

`console.log` inside loop is executed till value of `a` remains less than 5. However, after the last loop iteration when the value of `a` becomes 4 and it's printed by the inside `console.log`, `a++` increments its value to 5 and then the for-loop condition `a<5` fails and the loop breaks. Afterwards, the compiler executes `console.log` outside the for-loop where the value of `a` is already 5.

The key point is, the for-loop breaks only when the value of `a` turns 5. But as soon as it breaks, `console.log` inside the loop won't be executed and the compiler would execute line of code next to the for-loop.

Furthermore, you've declared the variable `a` outside the loop and its scope exists even the loop is finished.

I hope it clarifies the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, `global`.

Here the variable `a` is declared `globally`, and redeclaring the variable makes it `original value changed`,

So when running inside for loop a is firstly initialised with 0 thus replacing 10, and when the loop terminates at a is equal to 5, because 5<5, which is false.

Thus consoling the value 5 to the outer for loop.
So the conclusion is `var` scope is functional which is responsible for the changes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

As your loop ends after the condition,`console.log ("Number inside is " + a);` It will print 0,1,2,3,4 and outside this loop it will print 5 loop ends but value of a remain in it's scope and print 5.
If you will use let it will give 10 because you have declared a variable `var a=10` above the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Because of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), The `a` is re-assign to `0` at first loop instead of declaring new variable. This is how the browser executes your code:

```
var a = 10;

for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    console.log ("Number inside is " + a);
}; //Prints: "Number inside is 0...1...2...3...4"

console.log ("Number outside is " + a);
//Prints: "Number outside is 5
```